# How to get status of a video player in BlackBerry

Tags: video, blackberry, status, playback

I want to play a 10 seconds long video in BlackBerry. On video playing completion I want go to another screen. For this I want know the current status of player (e.g. playing, stopped, paused etc.).

Here is the code I am using now. Need help on this issue.

```java
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/video/battery_tip.mp4");
player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "video/mp4");
player.prefetch();
player.realize(); 
VideoControl vc = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
Field fld = (Field) vc.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
vc.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
vc.setVisible(true);
add(fld);
player.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the interface [PlayerListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/PlayerListener.html).

> PlayerListener is the interface for receiving asynchronous events
>   generated by Players. Applications may implement this interface and
>   register their implementations with the addPlayerListener method in
>   Player.

To get current status of a [Player](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Player.html), add an instance of `PlayerListener` to it.

```java
player.addPlayerListener(new MyPlayerListener());
```

A demo implementation of `PlayerListener`

```java
class MyPlayerListener implements PlayerListener {
    public void playerUpdate(Player player, String eventType, Object eventData) {
        try {
            if (eventType == PlayerListener.END_OF_MEDIA) {
                // go to next screen
            } else if (eventType == PlayerListener.CLOSED) {
                // go to next screen
            } else if (eventType == PlayerListener.ERROR) {
                // go to next screen
            } else if (eventType == PlayerListener.STOPPED) {
                // go to next screen
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```